# Rowsource behavior not updating/resetting the listbox without reloading the userform // getting column headers with list = ranges

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have the following code that works, BUT only on me unloading(x) the userform and reloading it. The listbox(being the DatabaseViewer) loads on userform initialize.

The testbutton will take the string input on a TextBox and fuzzy search the original database and copy out the database to a temporary sheet which allows for the rowsource formula to work.

**I would have preferred to use list = Ranges instead of RowSource but from my google searches it appears that that is the only way to get headers reliably, if there is an alternative to getting headers please do share!!**

```
Private Sub testButton_Click()
Dim dataworksheet As String

dataworksheet = ActiveSheet.Name

MsgBox (dataworksheet)

Range(Cells(getFirstDataAreaRow, getApplicableColumn("Original Name")), Cells(getLastDataAreaRow, getApplicableColumn("Original Name"))).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & searchByName.Value & "*"
Range(Cells(getFirstDataAreaRow, getApplicableColumn("Number")), Cells(getLastDataAreaRow, getlastDataAreaColumn)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Sheets("Temp").Activate
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets(dataworksheet).Activate
MsgBox (dataworksheet)
Dim TempDataArea As Range
Set TempDataArea = Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Cells(getFirstDataAreaRow("Temp") + 1, getlastDataAreaColumn("Temp")), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Cells(getLastDataAreaRow("Temp"), getlastDataAreaColumn("Temp")))


        With databaseViewer
            .ColumnCount = getlastDataAreaColumn("Temp")
            .ColumnHeads = True 'only works if you are using rowsource
            .ColumnWidths = "0;;4 in" 'THIS SETS the number column to HIDDEN!
            .RowSource = TempDataArea.Cells.Address 'rowsouce only works with address, .list works with ranges
        End With


End Sub
```

Comment: try `.RowSource = vbNullString` to reset it before you set the correct `.RowSource`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ That doesn't work sadly!

Comment: Sadly *"doesn't work"* doesn't contain any information for us to help you. Always describe exactly what actually happens instead of what you expect please.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Sorry about not providing enough information. My bad.

The behavior remains the same as I described. Doesn't work until i reload the userform.

I also tried combinations of ( and reversing their orders)

.rowsource = ""
.rowsource = vbNullString 

To the same result as above

Comment: Try `.RowSource = TempDataArea.Cells.Address(External:=True)` instead and specify the UserForm for `databaseViewer` like `Me.databaseViewer` or `MyUserForm.databaseViewer`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ 

similiar results. Doesn't work without reloading. Is there a way to reactivate the listbox? maybe that might work.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. If I add only a ListBox on a UserForm and a button to change the `.RowSource` of the ListBox it always updates immediately by just setting it like `.RowSource = TempDataArea.Cells.Address`. This should work.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ yeah I imagine there might be some dependencies that is causing this interesting problem. let me have a look and let you know if I realise the problem.

Thanks man!

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Found the error, the data was pointing to the wrong areas to populate from.

Thank you for your supreme patience friend.